# CRON problems... "Could not open input file:"

Tags: centos, cron

We're getting emails from Cron Daemon telling us the follwing message:

> Could not open input file:
>   /var/www/vhosts/justhome.co/httpdocs/cron.php

The reason why it cannot open the input file is the domain is no longer there... it has been deleted.

Where would I be able to find the file that is referencing the old domain? I've had a dig through the etc folder for cron jobs but can't see anything obvious relating to it.

We are running Centos and Plesk on a dedicated server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User crontabs are usually found in `/var/spool/cron` you may find what you're looking for in one of them.

Don't edit the user crontab file directly, use the

```
sudo crontab -u user -e
```

command. If you want to delete the user's crontab use

```
sudo contab -u user -r
```

This ensures that the cron daemon knows what's been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/var/spool/cron/` folder.